# How can I stop Toronto District Schoolboard's's Academic Workspace from intercepting my gmail login on my laptop?

Tags: gmail

I can access my gmail from my phone, but on my laptop, I'm redirected to tdsb's login. I don't have an account with them, but my daughter does, and her email is connected to mine. How can I regain access to my email?

Answer (score -1):

You can also ask your student to log into the account, and then from there you will be able to switch between accounts from the user icon at the top right corner of the browser screen.

Answer (score -1):

Could be a captive portal. Like in malls with public WIFI the first time you have to "log in".